# .toFixed() called on negative exponential numbers returns a number, not a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, tofixed

I noticed that when calling `toFixed` against a negative exponential number, the result is a number, not a string.

First, let's take a look at specs.

> ### [`Number.prototype.toFixed (fractionDigits)`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.7.4.5)
>
> Return a `String` containing [this Number value](http://es5.github.io/#this-Number-value) represented in decimal fixed-point notation with *fractionDigits* digits after the decimal point. If *fractionDigits* is `undefined`, `0` is assumed.

What actually happens is (tested in Chrome, Firefox, Node.js):

```
> -3e5.toFixed()
-300000
```

So, the returned value is `-3e5`. Also, notice this is **not** a string. It is a number:

```
> x = -3e5.toFixed()
-300000
> typeof x
'number'
```

If I wrap the input in parentheses it works as expected:

```
> x = (-3e5).toFixed()
'-300000'
> typeof x
'string'
```

Why is this happening? What is the explanation?

Comment: It's parsed as `-(3e5.toFixed())`

Comment: Moral of the story: Calling methods on literal numbers is fraught with peril. For instance, `5.toFixed()` is a syntax error. Use parens or variables to avoid falling into pitfalls. (You can do the `5.toFixed()` thing with `5..toFixed()` but...just don't. Parens are nice and reliable: `(5).toFixed()`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Definitely, I was just curious what was going on. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess this is because of higher precedence of the member ('.') operator compared to the sign operator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 5):

What is happening here is the order of operations. Lets break it down:

First what's going to to happen is 3e5 is going to return a number (300000), then toFixed will be called on in, turning it into a string, then the sign operator is going to be executed, coercing the string back to a number.

Comment: it's right, however, there is no the conception of `the sign operator` in javascript. The finally step is that **the Unary negation operator** attempts to convert its operand into a number in the process of evaluation. u can see [Unary_negation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation_(-))